How I need fix error desired capabilities
 def new_task(logg): #===Создает заявку в демо2===
>       driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor=executor,
            desired_capabilities=capabilities)
E       TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'desired_capabilities'

autoTest.py:56: TypeError
=================================================================================== short test summary info ===================================================================================
FAILED autoTest.py::Test1::test_par_1 - TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'desired_capabilities'

I have a error in my python autotest and I use Selenoid
But maybe I need to use older version on my driver?
my actual version Version: 3.9.0
I have a error in my python autotest and i use Selenoid
But maybe i need to use older version on my driver?
my actual version Version: 3.9.0

This question is similar to: ChromeDriver desired_capabilities has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object with options kwarg. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Replace desired_capabilities with options as :
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions

driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=executor, options=options)

